# Какая процедура уменьшает переменную на единицу?

Tags: delphi, процедуры

Какая процедура уменьшает переменную на единицу?

Comment: декремент i--;

Comment: [**Dec**][1]

[1]: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Dec@.html

Comment: Прозреваю вопрос с подвохом, **функция**, но уменьшает **переменную** %)

Comment: Ну извините, процедура.

Comment: Дык теперь ответ - `Dec` :-)

Comment: @johniek_comp, вы о чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dec()

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Pred`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pred) 
(Ахтунг, документация кривая! Тип результата д.б. `Ordinal`)

Answer (score 2):

Это операция декремента.

```
procedure Dec(var X [ ; N: longint ] );

Dec(x);      // уменьшить переменную x на 1
Dec(x, 10);  // уменьшить x на 10
```